# Laravel > Eloquent eager load in batches

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to get half a million rows from database using Laravel and export them into excel file. 
The problem is, that the resource im exporting has quite a few joins and when I export it like this ( pseudo code )

```
 foreach( myResources as resource ) {
   convertToExcelRow(resource);
   convertToAnotherExcelRow(resource->joinedTable);
 }
```

Laravel creates half a million queries + another that much to make the joins.

Now, for most situations, I could use eager loading, which will load everything in one query(much faster) but for such large queries, laravel will trigger a mysql error(plus it is very slow) because the list of row ids that goes into `WHERE id IN`( hundreds of thousands of ids)

Is there a Laravel way to eager load using batches ?
E.g break that 100 000 id list down into 10 queries, each 10 000 ids or something similar.

Comment: You can try [pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination), or do a manual limit/offset within a loop. Without seeing the queries themselves, it's hard to determine what would be the best way to do that.

Comment: You can use batches queries and break it, you can cut the query in order to shorten the query time and avoid sql error. And try using cronjobs and let cronjobs do the work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using the `chunk` method to break the task down in to manageable parts like so:

```
Resource::with(['relationship1','relationship2'])->chunk(500, function($resources) {
    $resources->each(function($resource) {
        $this->convertToExcelRow($resource);
        $this->convertToAnotherExcelRow($resource->joinedTable);
    });
});
```

#### Note:

Play around with the chunk sizes (500 is just an example). In this case you should get 2 queries for every 500 rows in your table. If you choose 5000, your query could would decrease by a factor of 10 but you load time may not improve due to the increased amount of joins being requested.

Comment: If anyone else comes across this - you can reduce the spreadsheet memory overhead massively with https://opensource.box.com/spout/faq/